# MacPorts on mountain lion - cannot install apache2 due to gettext package

Tags: macos, mac, macports

I have been having problem with installing gettext package from macports. When I am launching

```
 /opt/local/bin/port -v install apache2
```

it checks dependencies, and continues with gettext package installation. But the configure process freezes here:

```
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
```

and nothing happens.. can wait hours, nothing changes.

I tried to configure, make, make install manually for that package and it went all fine. But, when same configure is launched by ports, it hangs there. Question:

1) How can that be fixed?
2) Maybe I can somehow manually tell ports, that I installed that gettext package manually already?

Sorry, if wrong "site" for this question. Felt most proper one.

---

sudo port -v install apache2 solved the problem :/

still unbelievable, that same operation from root user was hanging..

Comment: You should run as `sudo /opt/local/bin/port -v install apache2` so that it runs as the correct user

Comment: oh my. i was launching it from root user, entering it via sudo su

Comment: Mark, post your comment as answer - so I can mark it as resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run macport port command as root best using port as shown in all the examples in the [Macports guide](http://guide.macports.org/) This is so that all the processes are set up as the correct user and the files are saved no changeable by other users.

e.g.
`sudo /opt/local/bin/port -v install apache2`

Answer (score 1):

Found this answer at http://theengguy.blogspot.com/2012/05/macports-install-gettext-hangs-on-later.html

---

If you are having issues with the installation of gettext and other packages hanging on macports, its most probably due to JAVA_HOME not being set. Set it and it should work:

```
# export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework
# /opt/local/bin/port install gettext
```

---

You probably have JAVA_HOME set in your user's environment, but not in root's.  While logged in as root, I set JAVA_HOME and successfully built gettext.  I've since added this to ~root/.profile so I don't have to remember it in 6 months...